# cannot connect Peerjs in angular

Tags: angular, peerjs

tsconfig.json:::

{
"compileOnSave": false,

"compilerOptions": {

```
"baseUrl": "./",

"outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",

"forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
"strict": true,
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
"esModuleInterop": true,
"noImplicitOverride": true,
"noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
"noImplicitReturns": true,
"noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
"sourceMap": true,
"declaration": false,
"downlevelIteration": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"moduleResolution": "node",
"importHelpers": true,
"target": "es2017",
"module": "es2020",
"lib": [
  "es2020",
  "dom"
]
```

},

"angularCompilerOptions": {

```
"enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
"strictInjectionParameters": true,
"strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
"strictTemplates": true
```

}
}

---

angular service file :::

import Peer from 'peerjs';
.
.
.

this.actPeer = new Peer({debug:3}) **("peerjs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default(...).Peer is not a constructor")**

---

import { Peer } has same warn..

a year ago same code not has a problem like this..

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. It's in `package.json`. Using a new regular install of PeerJS solves problem. I simply must add to global `var ParcelRequire` to pass anew appeared problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).